# Why doesn't CMake / include_external_msproject propagate platform argument?

Tags: cmake, crypto++

I'm trying to link a Windows application against [Crypto++](https://github.com/weidai11/Crypto++). To do this I made the following simple `CMakeLists.txt`, including the `cryptlib.vcxproj` project via [`include_external_msproject`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/command/include_external_msproject.html), specifying Win32 or x64 for `PLATFORM` depending on build configuration.

```
cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 3.8)

project(test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCE_FILES})

if( ${CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P} MATCHES "8" )
    set(CRYPTOPP_PLATFORM x64)
    message(STATUS "Platform: ${CRYPTOPP_PLATFORM}")
else()
    set(CRYPTOPP_PLATFORM Win32)
endif()

if( ${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE} MATCHES "Debug" )
    set(CRYPTOPP_MODE Debug)
else()
    set(CRYPTOPP_MODE Release)
endif()

include_external_msproject(cryptopp ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/cryptopp/cryptlib.vcxproj PLATFORM ${CRYPTOPP_PLATFORM})

add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME} cryptopp)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/cryptopp/${CRYPTOPP_PLATFORM}/Output/${CRYPTOPP_MODE}/cryptlib.lib)
```

To generate the Win32 project I run `cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017" ..`, followed by `cmake --build . --config Release` and all is fine; Crypto++ is built for platform Win32 and the application is linked against it.

```
cryptlib.vcxproj -> C:\code\Test\cryptopp\Win32\Output\Release\cryptlib.lib
```

My problem is that when building for x64, `cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" ..`, followed by `cmake --build . --config Release` the Crypto++ project is still built for Win32, naturally resulting in a failed build.

Opening and building the generated x64 project in VS2017 works - Crypto++ is built for x64 with an output file in 
`..\cryptopp\x64\Output\Release\cryptlib.lib` as expected.

I've tried this with the latest CMake, 3.12.1

**Q:** Have I misunderstood how `include_external_msproject` functions? How do I make the Crypto++ project build for x64 when built outside of Visual Studio?

Comment: Related, Crypto++ has CMake project files at [cryptopp-cmake](https://github.com/noloader/cryptopp-cmake). Also see [CMake](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/CMake) on the Crypto++ wiki.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ended up as a [bug](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/18308) and is fixed in [CMake 3.13.0](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/milestones/26)